# confusion in context variable and Context Class in soap Ui

Tags: groovy, soapui

`context,testRunner` variables(built-in) in SoapUI are objects/instances of which classes in soapui api.

I was under impression that context variable is an instance of

**com.eviware.soapui.impl.wadl.inference.schema.Context**

but in the Context class i could not find exapnd method which we use regualrly as shown below

```
context.expand('${#level#request}')
```

Please some body clarify...if both are difference where can i find list of all methods of context variable

Thanks

Comment: Kavitha, please check my answer to see if that helps to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The class of the context variable could be different depending on context.

The best way to get the class name to print it out:

```
log.info( context.getClass() )
```

If we talk about `groovy script`  test step then context should be

`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestRunContext` if you run just your script without running the whole test case.

`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext` if you run the whole or part of the test case including your script.

probably it could be other for different soapui project types..

So, what is the context of your groovy script?

Btw, how did you get `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wadl.inference.schema.Context` ?

Comment: i came thru the Context class in some other thread of forums..https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wadl/inference/schema/Context.html

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI initializes certain variables in certain level.

Here are the list of variables available at different level.

**Project Setup Script**

- context
- project
- runner
- log

Similarly, below variables available at **Test Suite Setup Script**

- context
- testSuite
- runner
- log

And also certain variables available in Test Case Setup Script.

The same is with **TearDown Scripts** as well.

However, If I understand right, you were referring to `Groovy Script` test step.

And the following variables are available there are:

- testRunner
- context
- log

To be more precise, `context.expand()` is used to read certain property values either from test case, suite or project.

In order to read **test case level** property, `CASE_PROPERTY`
User one of the two:

1. context.expand('${#TestCase#CASE_PROPERTY}')
2. context.testCase.getPropertyValue('CASE_PROPERTY')

In order to read test suite level property, `SUITE_PROPERTY`
User one of the two:

1. context.expand('${#TestSuite#SUITE_PROPERTY}')
2. context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('SUITE_PROPERTY')

In order to read test project level property, `PROJECT_PROPERTY`
User one of the two:

1. context.expand('${#TestSuite#SUITE_PROPERTY}')
2. context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('SUITE_PROPERTY')